# Wont download file to My documents folder

Tags: c#, activex

One of my customers having a problem with my ActiveX control. The ActiveX is supposed to download an Excel file, save it in a folder in My documents and then Run Excel and open the file.

Here is the code snippet for downloading and opening the file:

```
    private string Checkout(string strFileUrl, string strPhysicalDir, string strPhysicalName)
    {            
        string strMyDocumentFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string strCiroDocFolder = String.Format(@"{0}\CiroDoc", strMyDocumentFolder);
        string strCheckoutFolder = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", strCiroDocFolder, strPhysicalDir);
        string strFilePath = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", strCheckoutFolder, strPhysicalName);

        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(strCiroDocFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strCiroDocFolder);

            if (!Directory.Exists(strCheckoutFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strCheckoutFolder);

            if (File.Exists(strFilePath))
                File.Delete(strFilePath);

            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(strFileUrl, strFilePath);               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }

        return Run(strFilePath);
    }

    private string Run(string strFilePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(strFilePath))
            return "filenotfound";

        if (IsExecutable(strFilePath))
            return "isexecutable";

        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strFilePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //This get returned
            return String.Format("{0} ({1})", e.Message, strFilePath);
        }

        return "success";     
    }
```

The Run method returns the exception "an error occurred when the command is sent to the program".

When I check the My documents folder, the file is not there. Since it's not there, I would expect the Run method stop and return "filenotfound".

This confuses me. Why does the `File.Exists` return `true`? Is it Windows file virtualization that kicks in and the file is saved in VirtualStore folder? If so, how can stop that behaviour? Or could it be something else in my customer's machine that causes this behaviour?

I haven't been able to reproduce this problem on my own machine yet. If you know how I would be grateful.

My customer's computer setup

- OS: Windows 7
- Browser: IE 10
- Antivirus: McAfee

If there is some relevant information Im missing I'll try to get it.

Comment: I would try to set a breakpoint to check if the values passed to the function are effectively what you expect to be. Also, using the Path.Combine method will help a lot removing all that string concats.

Comment: I can verify that strFilePath is what I expect it to be, since I return it along the Exception. Thanks for the Path.Combine method, did not know about that one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having Internet Explorer in Protective mode and UAC enabled causes `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strFilePath);` not to run as expected.

Using this code instead will open the Excel file, even in Protective mode.

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "excel";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"""{0}""", strFilePath);
myProcess.Start();
```